# How to select how many subdivisions will a curve have?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I have a path curve, I want it to give it 100+ subdivisions, but I don't have the time to do it manually, is there any way to select the number subdivisions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go into edit mode, press <kbd>W</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>, go to the <kbd>T</kbd> menu and find this window:
[image]

Enter the desired number of subdivisions as shown.

Answer (score 5):

go into edit mode, subdivide pressing <kbd>W</kbd> and type the number of subdivisions you need.
[image]

Comment: Hey XD That's my answer XD

Comment: It happens all the time...

Comment: Yeah, no problem, just kind of funny.

Comment: It took me a few seconds more to do the Giff...

Comment: Exactly, I was thinking that was probably what did it. It happened to Gandalf3 recently too, he normally has three or four in his answers XD